# What are my storage options when writing Rack middleware for Rails applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, persistence, rack, rack-middleware

Assuming my Rack middleware is designed specifically for Rails applications, what storage options do I have? For instance, is there a way for me to read from / write to the Rails cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is, the Rails cache is independent from Rack, you can use it like this:

```
Rails.cache.read("city")   # => nil
Rails.cache.write("city", "Duckburgh")
Rails.cache.read("city")   # => "Duckburgh"
```

You can read more about caching on Rails at [the Rails caching tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores).

You could also roll your own solution like connecting to a Redis/Memcached instance, talking to a NoSQL database. There are plenty of solutions for this issue.